# Parse AWS ec2 DescribeInstanceStatusOutput JSON response using Golang

Tags: json, go, amazon-ec2, aws-sdk

Hi all I am a beginner trying to learn Go. I am trying to get the status of my EC2 instance using AWS SDK with Golang. I was successfully able to get a JSON response for my instance. I am however, having issues trying to parse the JSON response to get the instance state.

The following is how I get the JSON response:

```
result, err := ec2Svc.DescribeInstanceStatus(input)
```

where input is of type ec2.DescribeInstanceStatusInput

The following is the JSON response I get:

```
{
 "InstanceStatuses": [
  {
   "AvailabilityZone": "ap-southeast-2b",
   "Events": null,
   "InstanceId": "[VALIDIMAGEID]",
   "InstanceState": {
    "Code": 16,
    "Name": "running"
   },
   "InstanceStatus": {
    "Details": [
     {
      "ImpairedSince": null,
      "Name": "reachability",
      "Status": "passed"
     }
    ],
    "Status": "ok"
   },
   "OutpostArn": null,
   "SystemStatus": {
    "Details": [
     {
      "ImpairedSince": null,
      "Name": "reachability",
      "Status": "passed"
     }
    ],
    "Status": "ok"
   }
  }
 ],
 "NextToken": null
}
```

I then parse the result which is of type DescribeInstanceStatusOutput to String and then pass it to the function  parseJson where I attempt to parse the JSON.

```
result, err := ec2Svc.DescribeInstanceStatus(input)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println("Error", err)
    } else {
        parseJson(result.String())
        //fmt.Printf("%v\n", result)
    }

func parseJson(ec2StatusDescription string){
    //var x string = ec2StatusDescription.String()
    //fmt.Print(ec2StatusDescription)
    data := []byte(ec2StatusDescription)
    var instanceOutputs InstanceOutput
    json.Unmarshal(data, &instanceOutputs)
    fmt.Print(instanceOutputs.InstanceStatuses[0].InstanceState.Name)
}

type InstanceOutput struct {
    InstanceStatuses [] InstanceStatuses
    NextToken *string
}

type InstanceStatuses struct {
    AvailabilityZone string
    Events *string
    InstanceId string
    InstanceState InstanceState
    InstanceStatus InstanceStatus
    OutpostArn *string
    SystemStatus SystemStatus
}

type InstanceState struct {
    Code int
    Name string
}

type InstanceStatus struct {
    Details []   InstanceDetails
    Status string
}

type InstanceDetails struct {
    ImpairedSince *string
    Name string
    Status string
}

type SystemStatus struct {
    Details [] InstanceDetails
    Status string
}
```

I am trying to print the instance state but I keep getting index out of range, and this is because the JSON is not being parsed properly. What am i missing here that's causing the json to not parse correctly? Or am I getting it completely wrong in what I'm doing here? Any help would be highly appreciated.

Comment: Don't ignore the error returned by `json.Unmarshal`. And why are you calling `result.String()`? The output of `DescribeInstanceStatus` is already a Go struct [DescribeInstanceStatusOutput](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-go/api/service/ec2/#DescribeInstanceStatusOutput). You're turning a Go struct (defined in the AWS library) into a pretty string (not technically json), then parsing it again into your own version of the struct.

Comment: You're right, I got it all wrong. Thank you so much for you help. I am now able to print the instance status using the strut response.